# How to use parameters const char *format in custom printf

Tags: c, printf

I'm looking for a function that print log information, in order to debug my program.
This function must look at a boolean and decide if write the log in a file or to the console.

```
int useFile;
int log_informations( ? )
{
  if(useFile)
  {
     // open/close FILE *pf omitted
     fprintf(pf, ? );
  }
  else
  {
    printf( ? );
  }
  return 0;
}

int main()
{
  int answer = 42;
  log_informations("The answer is %d.", answer);
  return 0;
}
```

Can you help me with the parameter? I did not found any reference.

NB: In this question I made things clear and simpler as they were in my context, so I do not need workaround but, possibly, a simple answer.

Thank you in advance ;)

Comment: You need to use vfprintf or vprintf instead.

Comment: Unrelated: you can `fprintf()` to `stdout` ... `fprintf(usefile ? pf : stdout, "...", ...);`

Comment: [vfprintf example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/vfprintf/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As other mentioned, you don't need to actually write a function. A macro could help here:

```c
#define LOG(fmt, ...)    fprintf(logToFile ? fileLogger : stdout, fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)
```

To answer your question you can look at how `printf` and `vprintf` work:

```c
int printf(const char *format, ...);
int vprintf(const char *format, va_list arg);
```

`printf` is a [variadic function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/variadic) and you want to provide your own version that wraps `vprintf` and `vfprintf`.

```c
#include <stdarg.h> // needed for va_list, va_start, and va_end.

int my_printf(const char *format, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    int ret;

    va_start(ap, format);
    if (useFile) ret = vfprintf(pf, format, ap);
    else ret = vprintf(format, ap);
    va_end(ap);

    return ret;
}
```

EDIT: as @phuclv mentioned, if you want to include file, line, and/or function information in your log a macro is the only way. For example, for appending file and line information you could do something like this:

```c
#define LOG(fmt, ...)    fprintf(logToFile ? fileLogger : stdout, __FILE__ ":" STRINGIFY(__LINE__) " " fmt, ##__VA_ARGS__)

#define STRINGIFY_HELPER(x) #x
#define STRINGIFY(x)        STRINGIFY_HELPER(x)
```

You need `STRINGIGY` for `__LINE__` because it is an `int`.

Comment: and a macro is the only way to get line numbers, file names and function names in C so logging feature almost always uses macros: `#define LOG(fmt, ...)    fprintf(logToFile ? fileLogger : stdout, fmt "[" __FILE__ ":" __LINE__ ":" __func__ "]", ##__VA_ARGS__)`

Comment: `__LINE__` is usually an `int` (not sure what the standard says, but that's how it is in GCC, clang, and MSVC). You can stringify it with the usual macro trick: ```#define STRINGIFY_HELPER(x) #x
#define STRINGIFY(x) STRINGIFY_HELPER(x)```